how much vs. how much + uncountable noun

I wondered how much sugar was in the coke.


how much sugar : an interrogative and subject


I wondered how much sugar in the coke was.


how much : an interrogative
sugar in the coke : a subject

Q. Are two sentences above grammatically correct?
Is 'how much' used only when asking a price?
And Is 'how much + uncountable noun' used only when asking amount?

As it stands, #2 is completely invalid syntactically. Normally it would be #2a I wondered how much sugar there was in the coke, but at the margins of acceptability it could be #2b I wondered how much sugar in the coke there was. I don't like #2b in this exact context, but I have no problem with You'd be surprised how many supporters of the terrorists there are.
